# Don't hide navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm building an app where I want to show some additional data about content displayed on screen via navigation drawer. 
By default, after clicking out of the drawer it's hidden - I would like to override this behavior. 
What I want is to keep drawer open as long as I'm clicking outside of it and also redirect click events to underlying views.

Is this possible? If not with drawer layout, how can I implement this functionality?

Comment: you can prevent drawer to close using `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @joao2fast4u actually not yet, I created fixed left fragment for now and I will look at this later.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by extending DrawerLayout and overriding onInterceptTouchEvent:

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
    // .... Constructors here...

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        if (isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            switch (ev.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the above example you will be able to interact with underneath content when right drawer is opened. Don't foreget change DrawerLayout to CustomDrawerLayout in your main layout xml file.

Also you may need to hide shadowy overlay which is shown above the rest of the layout, for that use:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: I will verify this and let you know but it looks promising